# Multithreaded C code breaks under compiler optimization, works perfect without it, is this expected to happen, or is it definitely a bug?

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization, thread-safety

I have a network program which involves several interacting threads and a thread pool for overlapped network I/O.  I'm compiling with MinGW, which is gcc for Windows.

It works 100% fine without compiler optimization, across several different machines, however when I turn optimization on it breaks.

Should this be expected to happen, or is this revealing a bug that I need to fix?

Comment: it is more likely to be a bug that just isn't hit without compiler optimization than a bug caused directly by compiler optimization itself. without seeing the code in question its impossible to say what is actually happening.

Comment: Look for race conditions: missing volatiles, missing atomic operations, missing or incorrectly used synchronization primitives.

Comment: That depends on the compiler optimization you're enabling. Some (most?) compilers include some dangerous optimizations that can break code that's actually correct. Some also have bugs that only show up when you turn on optimization. The other 99.9% of the time, it's a problem in your code that was masked when optimization was turned off.

Comment: The joy of multithreaded code is that short of mathematically proving the program correct, there is no way to be sure that the code "works 100% fine", no matter how much you test it.  It's not unusual for multithreaded code to have bugs whose symptoms only become visible occasionally, e.g. out of every 1 gazillion runs (at random).  Most likely that is the case here, but the optimizations have changed something to make the fault happen often enough for you to notice it.  So be happy that the optimizer is making your debugging process easier for you :)

Comment: Sounds good, I'll work the bug out.  Thanks very much

Comment: Is it blocked, livelocked, AV'd or just behaving badly in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that it is revealing a bug that you need to fix. It is most likely a race condition in the threading, but it's also possible that it's an aliasing violation.

One trick that might help you localize the problem, especially if you replicate it easily, is to do a binary search to find the affected file. Basically, compile half your files with optimization and half without. See if the code works or crashes. That will localize the problem to half your code. Repeat, narrowing down the files with the issue, until you localize it to a file. If needed, split that file in two and move code from one file to the other to figure out the chunk of code that fails when optimized and not when unoptimized.

Comment: +1 Good plan! I love a good pork chop.